# How to link a library from another library in QT

Tags: windows, qt, hyperlink

For example:

lib1 it's a library in lib1 path

lib2 it's a library in lib2 path that depends from lib1, that means:

the lib2 .pro file have:

LIBS += -L../lib1 -llib1

INCLUDEPATH += ../lib1

test it's a executable in test path that depends from lib2, that means:

the test .pro file have:

LIBS += -L../lib2 -llib2

INCLUDEPATH += ../lib2

I build lib1 and lib2 normaly but when I try to build test I get this error on Windows (but not on MAC):

In function 'function in lib2'

```
undefined reference to 'function in lib1'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `win32:LIBS += -L../lib1 -llib1` to test .pro file too.

Windows requires all the symbols to be resolved at link time, so if `test` needs `lib2` which itself needs `lib1` then `lib2` and `lib1` must both be linked with test.

Unixes (MacOSx, Linux,...) can link libraries with unresolvable symbols, so `test` will only need `lib1` at load time.

Comment: Actually GCC on Linux also complain about that, for me this is a bug, LIB1 doesn't have any relation with Test.

Comment: In a simple project like the example it works fine, but in my project this doesn't work, but for some odd reason works when I include the .cpp file in the main project: #include "xmlreader.cpp".